# How to create following formula Excel in Power BI and what does -100% mean in Excel formula?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

This might be something simple, but I am confused. Can anybody please tell me what does this -100% in excel formula is doing? I try to dig through online, it just points to me for meaning.

```
=(8.7/8.9)-100%
```

I am trying to create the exact same thing in Power BI, but it will give me an error message. How to create this excel formula in Power BI? 
[image]
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Can anybody please tell me what does this -100% in excel formula is doing?*

It's calculating how much is missing from `avg_Daily_submitted` vs `avg_Daily_Reqquired`

You did `8.7` but your target was `8.9`, so you failed. How much failed? `=(8.7/8.9)-100%`

By the way, doing `=(8.7/8.9)-100% = (8.7/8.9)-1`.

In this case, it returns `-2.25%` and `-2,25% = -0,2`, and that's how much you failed.

Comment: Thank you s much for the explanation. I did not know that before. It works on Power Bi too. Again, thank you